# How to bind left-shift+mouse-up/down-scroll to page-up/down in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-shortcuts, key-binding

I have found many ways to bind a key or key-combination to start a process or another key, how do I do it with mouse and keyboard combinations?

I want windows to do a page-up when hold shift and scroll up with the mouse, and vise versa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/).

Simply use this script:

```
+WheelUp::SendInput {Shift Up}{PgUp}{Shift Down}
+WheelDown::SendInput {Shift Up}{PgDn}{Shift Down}
```

The `+` means while shift is held.

Shift must be released before sending page up/down, otherwise it interferes (try holding shift and using the keyboard page up/down buttons). That's what `{Shift Up}` does.

Shift is pressed down again after sending the page up/down, so you can go more than one page without physically releasing the key.

Comment: Thank you, I installed AutoHotKey and used your script. Works perfectly! I was knee deep in C# trying to figure out global hooks to Keyboard and Mouse, however, this solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Refreshing Bob's answer in 2024 with the AHK v2 conversion:

```
+WheelUp::SendInput("{Shift Up}{PgUp}{Shift Down}")
+WheelDown::SendInput("{Shift Up}{PgDn}{Shift Down}")
```