# LeftClick + PgDn or PgUp hotkey

Tags: scrolling

I had for a while this function (in Word, in Chrome Bookmarks) in which I could grab for example a Bookmark with a left mouse-button holding down, and while holding the mousebutton, while hitting Page Up or Page Down to move (scroll) the Bookmark in the Bookmark list really fast, page by page.  Today this function does not work.  Something changed in the system, and I can not restore it.  I miss this function since it helped me organize the Bookmarks really fast instead of really slow with the one position by one scroll function.
Can anyone tell me how to restore this function?

Comment: Your question doesn't seem to be about your CPU or your OS. Please use the edit button to change the title of the question to better reflect what the question is actually about. Placing the OS and CPU info in the body may be helpful, and will be better than them being the title

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how the feature disappeared, but I am looking into solving the problem by creating a hotkey with AutoHotKey.  I have to study the script language however.  Any Help is welcome (this is a start: [How to bind left-shift+mouse-up/down-scroll to page-up/down in Windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/462795/how-to-bind-left-shiftmouse-up-down-scroll-to-page-up-down-in-windows-7))